# How to get data from one column based on a variable in another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get data from an input sheet and use it to update a database in another sheet without hardcoding column letters and row numbers. Here is a picture of my input sheet:

[image: Input Sheet]

**CONTEXT:**
Users input data into E. Columns G and H contain the field names (G) and the values input by the user (H). I want to get the values from Column H and then update the right record in the database (a different sheet) based on the ContractorID field (which is in Col A of the database sheet) and the field names in Column G (which are the column headers in my database sheet).

**MY ASK**
I'd like code that dynamically gets the values in Column H (without referencing "H") based on the field names in Column G (without referencing "G").

I don't know Google App script well enough, but I think the logic would look something like this:

Iterating for each field name in Column G:

1. Set variable for the field name in column G
2. Get the column with "FIELDNAMES" in row 1
3. Get the row # of the field name variable in the FIELDNAMES column
4. Get the column with "FIELDVALUES" in row 1
5. Get the cell value in the row # in the FIELDVALUES column

Then I can use that value to populate the right field in the database sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script accomplishes what you're looking to do: it finds the data without explicitly calling out columns, then matches the contractor ID in the database sheet, finds the corresponding columns for each item and inserts the data.

**EDIT**

*Added functions at the end to compare the input fields with the columns and use a toast notification to alert the user around what columns are missing.*

A couple of notes:

1. Check the sheet names of course. this should work even if the database is in a separate worksheet. Just need to update the variable accordingly.
2. I borrowed from [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272879/google-apps-script-combine-arrays-when-there-is-a-match-between-both-arrays) to merge the input and database arrays.
3. See it in action (I added a button to run the script) [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oqeWwnwaWEt053TQ-xM-y9KO3C9wBA0xVT5ojkBbdCw/edit?usp=sharing)

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const input = ss.getSheetByName("input")
const db = ss.getSheetByName("database")

function addRecord() {
  // Find the columns you want, then get all the data in the columns to an array called inputData
  var fieldRangeStart = input.createTextFinder("FIELDNAMES").findNext().getColumn()
  var inputData = input.getRange(1,fieldRangeStart,input.getLastRow(),2).getDataRegion().getValues()
  
  // In the database sheet, get the column headers and create an array called dataColumns that gives us those positions in the database sheet. 
  var headers = db.getRange(1,1,1,db.getLastColumn()).getValues().toString().split(",")
  var dataColumns = []
  for (var i=0; i<headers.length; i++){
    dataColumns.push([headers[i],i+1])
  }
  
  // Merge the arrays, matching the fieldName values in each.
  const data = inputData.map(x => dataColumns.filter(y => y[0] === x[0]).map(y => [x[0], y[1], x[1]])).flatMap(x => x)

  // Filter out the contractorID into its own variable
  const contractorID = data.filter(x => x[0] === "ContractorID").map(x => x[2])
  console.log(contractorID)

  //Now we have the contractorID to search for, and a data array that contains the field names, database column index, and input values for the data. Just need to find the row with the matching Contractor ID and then write the values to their respective columns. 
  //Start by getting all the values in the first column, except the header (start the range at Row 2).
  var contractors = db.getRange(2,1,db.getLastRow(),1).getValues()

  //Then find the contractor ID in the list. Add 2 to the row index because we need to account for the header (1 row) and the fact that the index is 0-based but rows start at 1 when doing A1 Notation.
  var contractorRow = contractors.flat(1).indexOf(contractorID.toString())+2

  //Finally, confirm the contractor is in the database, and then loop through the data array and write each item to its cell, using the column reference we already have and the new contractorRow reference we just acquired, or setting a new row if the contractor doesn't exist in the database. Issue toast notifications if input fields are missing from the db
  if(contractorRow === 1){
    var newRow = db.getLastRow()+1
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      db.getRange(newRow,data[i][1]).setValue(data[i][2])
    }
  } else {
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      db.getRange(contractorRow,data[i][1]).setValue(data[i][2])
    }
  }

  // Gather just the FIELDNAMES data from the input sheet into a new variable called inputFields, ignoring the first row and flattening the result so it's not a 2-dimensional array.
  var inputFields = input.getRange(2,fieldRangeStart,input.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat(1)

  // We already have the column headers in a variable called headers. Filter inputFields for NOT being included in the headers variable and also remove blank entries. 
  let missing = inputFields.filter(x => !headers.includes(x) && x != "")

  // Now trigger the toast notification
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Oops! These fields are missing from the database: ' + missing, 'Missing Columns')
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted! I tried changing field names and adding a new field, and the script dynamically adapted. I have been searching long and wide for this solution. I appreciate your notations -- they'll definitely help me unpack the script. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to add a small piece of code that tells the user if there are fields in inputData that don't match the fields in dataColumns -- i.e. that an input field will not be written to the database because the field does not exist there. I'm thinking that would be an iteration of the match code that records where there isn't a match (but only one way -- fields in inputData that aren't in dataColumns) followed by a toast notification. Is that possible?

Comment: I updated the answer to give you an alert with the missing fields.

Comment: I found a potential bug: if the contractor doesn't already exist in the database the code will overwrite the first row. I've corrected that so it just issues another toast notification. However, you could also create a new row with that new contractor ID if you wanted.

Comment: I found that same error and was trying to figure it out! Glad you caught it. Thank you for the alert code, too. And yes, creating a new row with the new contractor ID would be ideal. Thank you again. I'm new to Google app script, and I'm learning a ton through your coding and comments.

Comment: ok, it's updated to add the new row. Note that the entire bottom section is changed, since the toast notification for fields was embedded in the IF statement around whether the contractor was in the database.

Comment: @marcelloguerra Updated request: I'm using multiple sheets that run this same code because I have multiple users and they can't all use the same input sheet. The problem is this: When each user clicks Save at the same time on their respective input sheets, there appears to be a conflict with the newRow var resulting in one or more of the new rows not being added to the database (or being over-written by another). Can you think of a way to adjust the var newRow code to accommodate simultaneous running of the code? I apologize if I've not done a good job of explaining this!